# JSON object within object

Tags: java, json, rest

```
"fid": "123",
"farm_info": {
    "name": "Example Farm",
    "address": "Example Address",
    "phone": "111-111-1111",
    "web": ""
},
"personal_info": {
    "name": "MyName",
    "email": "myname@example.com",
    "phone": "111-111-0000"
},
"delivers_to": ["60001", "60002"]
```

This is an object returned as JSON. In JAVA fid would be a String and delivers_to would be an Array of strings. What data type would farm_info and personal_info be to have this JSON returned?

Answer (score 1):

A `class` is a custom defined data type in Java **(you can define the group of elements like structure in C)** and so, farm_info and personal_info are `Object` types.

So to parse your JSON, along with the data types you mentioned, you need the below custom defined datatypes (Java Classes).

```
public class FarmInfo {
     private String name;
     private String address;
     private String phone;
     private String ;web

     //Getter and Setter methods need to be generated
}

public class  PersonalInfo {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    //Getter and Setter methods need to be generated
}
```

You can refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/) for more about Classes and objects.

Also, refer [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) for understanding JSON parsing.

Comment: `Class` already is a Java object, best not to conflict those

Comment: got it, makes sense

Comment: So, it's `public class`, not `Class`

Comment: But they have to be in the same class called "Farmer"

Comment: Why they have to be in the same class ?

Comment: It's a requirement